# Get index of hash with hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this hash with wins, and I'm sorting it based on how many wins a player has ( making a highscore list). Now I'm getting each value out based on a players id. How do I get the index of the value I got. ( So I can get the highscore placement).

```
#Highscore list.
highscore = Hash.new

@users.each_with_index do |player, index|
  playerTotalGames = @finishedgames.where(log_id: player.id)
  playerTotalWins = playerTotalGames.where(winner: true)
  highscore[player.id] = playerTotalWins.length.to_i  
end

@highscore = highscore.sort_by{ |k, v| v }.reverse.to_h # Sort highscore list
```

Comment: I'm confused. Which value are you wanting the index of?

Comment: @jeffdill2 for example if I have a array of hashes that looks like this:
highscore = { Playerid1"=>0, "Playerid2"=>0} 

And I want to get the hash for Playerid2, like this: highscore[@user.id]. Now I want the index of this hash. So the index for Playerid2 will be 1 and index for Playerid1 will be 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
index = @highscore.keys.find_index(player.id)
```

But, since it looks like you're going to walk the `@highscore` hash in its sorted by score order, you could just use `with_index`

```
@highscore.each.with_index(1) do |(player_id, score), position|
    # use the block variables as you see fit
end
```

The `1` passed to `with_index` makes the position start from 1 and not the default 0, which might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

To further optimize your code, (assuming you are not using `playerTotalGames` variable elsewhere), you can just do `playerTotalWins = @finishedgames.where(log_id: player.id, winner: true)`

Comment: Thanks! Did not think of that ! Looks much cleaner!